# Eternal file copy?

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

I have a file share on a Windows 7 box in my local domain network and is accessed by about 10 users, usually with no problems.

Today I have a user that was trying to do a simple file copy of a 26MB QuickBooks file from her workstation to the file share via a mapped drive.  She couldn't make it work, so I logged in as her and tried, and encountered this odd behavior:

1. I can copy any file FROM the file share, no problem.
2. If I try to copy TO the file share, it says "Calculating" pretty much indefinitely.
3. If I wait long enough, it will show that it's copying at a few k (like 15kb per second).
4. If I cancel it takes about 10 minutes for it to cancel, during which all explorer windows become useless, as if the entire explorer process is waiting for a timeout.

More info:

I have tried this from both computers, and get the same problem if I copy from the workstation to the file share, or go to the file server and access the workstation via c$ and try to copy it from the other end.

For the 26MB QuickBooks file, even though it says "calculating" forever, if I cancel and then wait for it to finish canceling, after it's done, the file will actually be there, as if it copied over, but the copy process never realized that it finished copying.

Both computers are fast (8-core processors, 24GB RAM), and are on a gigabit network.  Neither seems to be having any other problems.

None of my other workstations has this problem.

If I use a DIFFERENT workstation, I can access her desktop via c$\users\her\desktop in one explorer window, access the file server in another explorer window, and copy it over via drag and drop with no problem at all - it copies over and is done in less than a second.

The file server is in my network, as are all other computers, but this particular workstation is NOT on the network - it's in it's own workgroup.  I assume this may have something to do with the problem, but it's been working this way for quite a while and hasn't had this problem before.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am reminded of http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/08/28/the-case-of-the-intermittent-and-annoying-explorer-hangs.aspx although it's not directly applicable, and might not be all that useful. (It is interesting though!)

Answer (score 1):

This makes me think about a similar issue i had a few times ago, and the cause was the `Task Offload` feature from Microsoft TCP/IP transport Layer.

On Client side, try (from an elevated command prompt) :

```
netsh interface ipv4 set global taskoffload=disabled
```

(Maybe you will have to reboot the client computer after that, i cannot remember).